# React Warning: Invalid Hook Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo

I'm having an issue pop up at multiple points in my application. I'm not sure what's causing the issue, but it seems to be any page dealing with state. I've built a few applications with very similar set ups and have never had this issue before. However, something seems to not be cooperating. React documentation states there's a few possibilities, including mismatched versions of react, duplicate versions of react, or an incorrectly called hook. I've checked my versions of react and react-dom to make sure they're compatible. I've also checked for duplicate versions of react and everything seems to be good on that end.

Below is an example of one of the hook calls that is throwing an error. I'm not sure what's going wrong, but if anyone could point me in the right direction it'd be so helpful. I'm happy to post any relevant code that might assist in getting an answer. Thank you!

Login.js

```
const LoginForm = (props) => {
    const [userFormData, setUserFormData] = useState({ username: '', password: '' });

    const [validated] = useState(false);

    const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);

    const [loginUser, { error }] = useMutation(LOGIN_USER);
```

When I comment out all of the useState's, the page will load partially instead of being a flat white screen.

EDIT: Here is an image of the error.

[image: Error]

Edit 2: Showing where LoginForm is called in App.js
App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
import Explore from './pages/Explore';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import './App.css';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql'
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

const App = () => {

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <div className='app'>
          <Navbar />
            <div className='container'>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
                <Route exact path='/profile:username?' component={Profile} />
                <Route exact path='/explore' component={Explore} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginForm} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is `LoginForm` called? Are you using the same major version of React and React DOM?

Comment: @CertainPerformance LoginForm is called on App.js, and I am using the same version of React and React DOM. I'll edit and add where it's called in app.js as well.